# voyager bread update custom primary key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, voyager

I know what the problem is, but even though I do everything, the error does not go away.
I'm doing a bread update and I'm getting this error;

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause

**Model**

```
class Kategoriler extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'kategori_id';
    protected $table = 'kategoriler';
    public $incrementing = false;
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

There is no problem in deleting bread in, I can also add, but such an error occurs because of the find function used in the update.

`protected $primaryKey = 'kategori_id';` When I define it, there is no problem with my other breads, but there is a problem with this bread, what could be the reason?

Note:Used query builder in the places I visited with override in the project.

**\TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBaseController**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $slug = $this->getSlug($request);

        $dataType = Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        // Compatibility with Model binding.
        $id = $id instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model ? $id->{$id->getKeyName()} : $id;

        $model = app($dataType->model_name);
        $query = $model->query();
        if ($dataType->scope && $dataType->scope != '' && method_exists($model, 'scope'.ucfirst($dataType->scope))) {
            $query = $query->{$dataType->scope}();
        }
        if ($model && in_array(SoftDeletes::class, class_uses_recursive($model))) {
            $query = $query->withTrashed();
        }

        $data = $query->findOrFail($id);

        // Check permission
        $this->authorize('edit', $data);

        // Validate fields with ajax
        $val = $this->validateBread($request->all(), $dataType->editRows, $dataType->name, $id)->validate();

        // Get fields with images to remove before updating and make a copy of $data
        $to_remove = $dataType->editRows->where('type', 'image')
            ->filter(function ($item, $key) use ($request) {
                return $request->hasFile($item->field);
            });
        $original_data = clone($data);

        $this->insertUpdateData($request, $slug, $dataType->editRows, $data);

        // Delete Images
        $this->deleteBreadImages($original_data, $to_remove);

        event(new BreadDataUpdated($dataType, $data));

        if (auth()->user()->can('browse', app($dataType->model_name))) {
            $redirect = redirect()->route("voyager.{$dataType->slug}.index");
        } else {
            $redirect = redirect()->back();
        }

        return $redirect->with([
            'message'    => __('voyager::generic.successfully_updated')." {$dataType->getTranslatedAttribute('display_name_singular')}",
            'alert-type' => 'success',
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code from the update method that uses the `where` method?

Comment: I shared the update function

Comment: What do you get if you do `dd($id)` for the first line of the `update` method?